# Bootstrap grid dividing column in decimal error

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

i am trying to divide the bootstrap grid column into 20 grids, i have used the following code:

```html
<div  style="width: 4.999999998%; margin-top: -27.5px; margin-left: 25px;"  class="col-md-.6 col-sm-6">
                <div style="height: 32.5px; width:65px;" class="location-block">
                  <div class="city-img">
                    <img src="images/wedding-location/location-1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="city">
                    <div class="overlay-bg"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="city-dtl text-center">
                    <h6 class="city-dtl-heading"><a href="#">New York</a></h6>
                    <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accus.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-pink hidden-xs">Read More</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
 <div  style="width: 4.999999998%;margin-top: -27.5px; margin-left: 25px;"  class="col-md-.6 col-sm-6">
                <div style="height: 32.5px; width:65px;" class="location-block">
                  <div class="city-img">
                    <img src="images/wedding-location/location-1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="city">
                    <div class="overlay-bg"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="city-dtl text-center">
                    <h6 class="city-dtl-heading"><a href="#">New York</a></h6>
                    <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accus.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-pink hidden-xs">Read More</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

i have used like this and i am able to divide it into only 12 columns, when i add a 13th one it goes below the row, can anyone please tell me whats wrong in my code, thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

each column take `4.999...%` + `25px` of the `margin-left`, so its more then 5%.

what you can do is:

1. `width: calc(4.999...% - 25px)`
2. just give all the columns `width:100%` and make the parent div `display:flex`

this is using flex, it will always sketch to 100% in total

```html
<div style="display:flex">
<div  style="width: 100%; margin-top: -27.5px; margin-left: 25px;"  class="col-md-.6 col-sm-6">
                <div style="height: 32.5px; width:65px;" class="location-block">
                  <div class="city-img">
                    <img src="images/wedding-location/location-1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="city">
                    <div class="overlay-bg"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="city-dtl text-center">
                    <h6 class="city-dtl-heading"><a href="#">New York</a></h6>
                    <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accus.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-pink hidden-xs">Read More</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            
 <div  style="width: 100%;margin-top: -27.5px; margin-left: 25px;"  class="col-md-.6 col-sm-6">
                <div style="height: 32.5px; width:65px;" class="location-block">
                  <div class="city-img">
                    <img src="images/wedding-location/location-1.jpg" class="img-responsive" alt="city">
                    <div class="overlay-bg"></div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="city-dtl text-center">
                    <h6 class="city-dtl-heading"><a href="#">New York</a></h6>
                    <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accus.</p>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-pink hidden-xs">Read More</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I have added example using `flex` (option NO.2) please take a look